# SQL Job output as YYMMDD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I would like to ask how am I able to export my output file as `YYMMDD.txt` format in SQL Job?

Right now i'm using SQL Token with

```
$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(DATE))$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(TIME)).csv
```

My output now will be

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv
```

I'm trying to figure out how I could get it to export as `YYMMDDHHMMSS.csv`

Appreciate any help, been searching but could not find any related question/answer.

Comment: Your first question is for `YYMMDD.txt`, then you second question is for `YYMMDDHHMMSS.csv`. Which one is it?

Comment: @PJMahoney you can't use SELECT syntax in configuring the name of an output file of a SQL Agent job.

Comment: Shawn, i'm trying to get YYMMDDHHMMSS.csv from my current output which is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv from using Token. Sorry for the confusion.